# Multi-language website language priority

Tags: cookies, locale, usability, multilingual

I haven't worked much with multi language websites and I'm wondering what the best way is to decided what language should be shown.

I myself go to `example.com`
My locale is en-GB so it automatically loads `example.com/en/` (English) for me.
I then select Dutch as the preferred language so my language cookie is set to nl-NL and I load `example.com/nl/` by default from now on.

Now someone links me (or I type it myself) to `example.com/en/somepage` while my cookie is set to nl-NL.

- Should the cookie take priority over the url and load the Dutch `example.com/nl/somepage` page? It is what I selected as my preferred language after all. It would be annoying to have to change it everyone time someone sends me a link.
- Should it load the English page AND set the cookie to English from now on?
- Should it just load the English page but still keep the cookie Dutch? And should everything on the page link to other English pages or link to Dutch (cookie language) pages.

And almost the same case but with locale and link on the first visit.
I have never been to `example.com`
Someone links me `example.com/nl/somepage` but my locale is en-GB.

- Should the URL take priority over locale and just load the Dutch version?
- Should the locale take priority over the URL and load the English version? And if I didn't set a preference this visit should the next visit check locale again or just load Dutch again?

In my specific case the pages have the exact same content in all languages. But I understand that in some cases different languages might have different content `example.com/en/shipping-info` might have different information than `example.com/nl/shipping-info`. Cookie priority over URL might not be such a great idea in the latter case.

Comment: I think `example.com/nl/myPageName` shouldn't redirect on english page because it will be like wrong url. You can provide language button or popup with available languages for users, who don't have cookie

Comment: Why do you want to use cookies for this in the first place? If on the English site, all internal links (except for the language switcher) include the `en` in the URL path, right?

Comment: Cookie to remember the language after the language switcher has been used. Don't want to force users to change the language every visit.